# GetDrive Info into Combo Box but concatenate 2 display members

Tags: c#, combobox

I'm trying to do a combo box that not only contains the drive letter but also the volume label.  I'm able to get one or the other by changing the displayMember.

I understand that I need to use .Expression to concatenate them before they go into the combobox.  But I'm confused.  Should I put the GetDrive into a table first and then do the expression...  then load it into the combobox?

Here's the code I have to get one display member:

```
    cmbDestDrive.DataSource = DriveInfo.GetDrives()
       .Where(d => d.DriveType == System.IO.DriveType.Removable).ToList();
    cmbDestDrive.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

This displays: `F:\`
I'd like to display `F:\USB Drive`

EDIT: Removed a useless line of code.

Comment: Do you want it to display it as if USB Drive is a folder? What you're looking for is DriveInfo.VolumeLabel, btw. Lastly, I can't see where you're displaying the data.

Comment: I know that VolumeLabel is the name.  I'm trying to figure out how to concatenate it with Name.  It's displayed in the combobox cmbDestDrive.

Comment: What is the type of cmbDestDrive?

Comment: Which dropdown list? WPF, WinForms, WebForms? Cos the one I found by googling (WebForms) doesn't have a DisplayMember property...

Comment: Yes Sorry.  It's WinForms.

Comment: Sounds like a ComboBox, that's probably why I couldn't find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to `Select` the string you want.

```
var drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives()
            .Where(d=>d.IsReady && d.DriveType == System.IO.DriveType.Removable)
            .Select(d => d.Name + " (" + d.VolumeLabel + ")"  )
            .ToList();

cmbDestDrive.DataSource = drives;
```

No need for `DisplayName`

Comment: What if (s)he wants to keep the original object?

Comment: I don't want to make any assumption at this point. He/She may want to use `SelectedIndex`. But I am open to OP's comments.

Comment: That could work.  But I am interested in keeping the other data so I can harness drive capacity.  I want to make sure all the data I'm copying to the USB drive is going to fit before I start the process.

Comment: @MattWiner Then why don'y you use `drives[cmbDestDrive.SelectedIndex].AvailableFreeSpace` etc.

Comment: @I4V...  well because I didn't think of that.  :)  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
cmbDestDrive.DataSource = DriveInfo.GetDrives()
   .Where(d => d.DriveType == System.IO.DriveType.Removable).Select(n => new { OriginalObject = n, Data = string.Format("{0}|{1}", n.Name, n.VolumeLabel)}).ToList();
cmbDestDrive.DisplayMember = "Data";
```

It should work (at least I think it should, I can't test it!).